# The text is cut on Safari browser

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I have problem with some text on safari browser. I don't know why text is cut on safari browser, although is everything good on other browser on windows. I don't use mac, so i don't know what is different on safari?

[image: This is how is look like.]

SCSS Code:

```
.serv-list {
  background-color: #6947d2;
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px 6vw;
  flex-direction: column;

  .serv-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 992px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: max-content;

  }

  h2 {
    font-family: "CocoGhoticBold";
    color: $RED_COLOR;
    font-size: 55px;
  }

  p {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    color: $WHITE_COLOR;
    font-size: 25px;

  }

  .right-box {
    text-align: right;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="serv-box right-box">
        <div>
          <h2>Script Writting</h2>
          <p>
            Bumping our heads together to make the perfect script for your ads /
            corporate videos and documentaries.
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="assests/icons/Script.png" alt="" />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not the wrong problem was in the font. Some kind of bug so it isn't shown properly on the safari browser. When I changed it, everything seems to be everything good.

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column` causes some bugs in Safari when using with padding or margin. You are not using any flex features other than `flex-direction: column` for the `.serv-list`. You can get the same result with the display: block. Remove it and just set `display: block`

```
.serv-list {
  background-color: #6947d2;
  padding: 50px 6vw;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but text is still cut. So i listened to you and try to remove align-items: center; in .serv-box. If i'm not wrong it worked. But do you think that can be solution? Of course text go to top, but doesn't cut anymore

Comment: Yes when i remove align-items it doesn't cut anymore, but this isn't because of that. It is because text go to top. When i use margin: auto to center again to center, it is again cut.